# how to sort a column by a given list in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Given this DataFrame and a list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['August', 2], ['July', 3], ['Sept', 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
order = ['July','Sept','August']

df
Out[310]: 
        A  B
1  August  2
0    July  3
2    Sept  6
```

I would like to reorder df['A'] using the given list so the final output is:

```
        A  B
1    July  3
0    Sept  6
2  August  2
```

Is there any way so that I could sort a column using a list of String?

Answer (score 5):

If possible sorting by datetimes generated by first 3 letters use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `key` parameter:

```
df = df.sort_values('A', key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str[:3], format='%b'))
print (df)
        A  B
1    July  3
0  August  2
2    Sept  6
```

Another solution with ordered categorical:

```
order = ['July','Sept','August']
df['A'] = pd.Categorical(df.A, ordered=True, categories=order)

df = df.sort_values('A')
print (df)
        A  B
1    July  3
2    Sept  6
0  August  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . But using Month is just an example, what if the column A is ['second','third','first','fourth'] how should I reorder the dataframe using order = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']?

Comment: @aaklbfklfkfkl - added new solution

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['August', 2], ['July', 3], ['Sept', 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
order = ['July','Sept','August']

df = df.set_index('A')
df = df.reindex(index = order)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: You can make it one line if you want:
df = df.set_index('A').reindex(index = order).reset_index()